# My T-SQL code shown here is not concatenating the items

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @hashThis NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @hashThis = CONCAT(Branch | '|' |
                       DiscountGroup | '|' |
                       ItemNumber | '|' |
                       PriceColumn |'|' |
                       LastUpdatedDate |'|' |
                       PMBasis |'|' |
                       PMOper |'|' |
                       PMMult |'|' |
                       DeletedOnDate |'|' |
                       PriceMatrixKey |'|' |
                       ODS_INSERT_TS)

SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5', @hashThis);
```

Comment: T-SQL uses + for concatenation, that looks like it came from a DB that uses |, swap the operator.

Comment: For the `CONCAT`, you just list the "parts" of the end result, separated by `,` (comma) - not `|` or anything like that ....

Comment: Is [`Concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) unclear?

Comment: CONCAT is new in 2012.  What version of sqlserver is being used?  It is not in 2008

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some effort to learning tsql syntax. You also left out some important information that you provided in your previous question. Lastly, you did not ask a question - just merely stated something was not working. How do you know? Did it generate an error? If so, post the complete error message. No one can read your mind or see your screen. Make an effort to provide useful information and context.

Based on what you provided in your other post, it seems like you want to generate a hash value for each row of a table based on the concatenated row values. So something like (note "like" - you need to correct it if it "doesn't work"):

```
select *, 
   HASHBYTES('MD5',concat(Branch, '|', DiscountGroup, '|', Item,...) as etl_checksum 
from ETL_SSIS.PriceMatrix_Work
order by ...;
```

I'll leave the task of adding all the desired columns to the hash function to you.